# How to read/parse dynamically generated client side content in Android using Java

Tags: android, web-scraping, jsoup, dynamic-data

I want to parse some dynamically generated client side data of a website ( data is generated in JavaScript using several `fetch()` commands ) in Android application using Java. Is there any way to access and parse these data. I want to get final HTML source after all client side JavaScript generation is finished. I suppose to parse them to [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/) HTML parser for the further processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jsoup can't parse JavaScript so it can't be used here.
It can be done with [Selenium webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/selenium-webdriver) or in case of Android  use [Selendroid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/selendroid).